# How to split word document into single page html files?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a word document of 20 pages. I want to save each page as a separate HTML file.

How can I do it?

I am using MS Word 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably write a script/macro to do this but you could make the same thing happen is less time by just saving each page manually as a .HTM or .HTML.  These options may be listed as "Web Page" or "Single File Web Page" in the Save as Type. drop down.

Answer (score -1):

Recently had the same problem and found this option: macros show how to break up a multipage Word document into separate files. The two macros use the page or section property of a Microsoft Word document to select and move through the document content. This code can be used in an automation scenario with Word not visible. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/216845